# Configurable Product stays on "in stock"

Tags: magento2

I'm working with Channable and my configurable products need to go to "**out of stock**" when the **simple products** are sold out.

> But the still be on "**in stock**".
>
> At the catalog configuration, the quantity is on **0.**

Does anyone know where I can change it?